# RenderPlot doesn't display twice

Tags: r, plot, shiny, render

I am trying to display some plots using renderplot(), and when i update y plots, it stays how it was before...

Let's have a look on my code:

**UI.R**

```
...
  uiOutput("firstGraph")
  uiOutput("seconfGraph")
  uiOutput("thirdGraph")
...
```

**server.R**

```
  observeEvent({input$CalcBtn,
    output$firstGraph <- renderUI ({
      if (dataTab$tabOne != 0) {
        plotOutput(plotsValue$graphOne)}
  }))

  observeEvent({input$CalcBtn,
    output$secondGraph <- renderUI ({
      if (dataTab$tabTwo != 0) {
        plotOutput(plotsValue$graphTwo)}
  }))

  observeEvent({input$CalcBtn,
    output$thirdGraph <- renderUI ({
      if (dataTab$tabThree != 0) {
        plotOutput(plotsValue$graphThree)}
  }))

  output$graphPlot121 <- renderPlot({...})
```

Here, `input$CalcBtn` is a button that makes a calculation and "refresh" the page. dataTab$tabOne (dataTab$tabTwo and dataTab$Three are approximately the same as dataTab$tabOne) is determinated by a function that reads an argument and transform it into a number. 0 if it must not print the plot and a number like 121 if it must print the plot 121. in plotsValue, the graphOne, graphTwo and graphThree are character strings made before using the value of dataTab, so it looks like "graphPlot121". So when I click the button, the programm makes everything great, expect displaying a second time the plot when I modify the inputs used inside the renderPlot.

The programm works well when I change from one plot to the other, but the problem comes when I try to display twice the same.

Please, help me if you know how to refresh the plot when I update it.

Comment: Without a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is hard to see the issue in your code.

Comment: I know @YBS, but the problem is that my code is about 5k rows, and it is difficult to do a MRE with it :/ I tried to explain it as clearly as possible, but I understand it's hard to see where I'm going. The only point you need to know, is  that I am looking for a solution to print twice the same plot to "update" it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"print twice the same plot to update it"*? Do you just want to update one of your existing plots (replace it) or do you want to render it a second time in a different location on the page?

Comment: Hello @julien.leroux5 , what I am trying to do here is to render the plot a second time in the same location to update it. But if you know how to update it without render it a second time, I'm taking every solutions

Comment: What changes are there to your graphs when doing the calculation after clicking the `input$calcBtn`? Why do you need `renderUI` and not just `renderPlot`? You should try to provide a MRE to address these questions because these points are not clear from the code you provided.

Comment: I added ```renderUI``` to use an if statement on the plot. If the value is TRUE, then it displays the plot, else it doesn't. So I put the ```renderUI```  to add a condition in my ui program. And when I click the ```input$calcBtn```  button, it applies to the plot some changes I made. All you need to know, is that the button gives different informations to the plot, and it works well because the program can change from a plot to an other. The only problem is when I try to change the values from the same plot. @julien.leroux5

Comment: you can still use `renderPlot` with an if statement: (`if (dataTab$tabOne != 0) output$firstGraph <- renderPlot ({plot(x, y) })     }`. you could perform the calculations following `input$calcBtn` in a different `observeEvent`, store the parameters in [reactiveValues](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/reactiveValues.html) and use them in the `renderPlot` to update the plot.